# i am trying to Fetch 1000000 with batchWise while Exporting but it showing this errror

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

[Error PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhKgZ.png)

am trying to Fetch 100000 with batchWise with 1000 records at a time  , so during Fetching it showing this error can anybody can suggenst a good method

my code is

```
  long NoOfRecords = 1000;
         long RecordsIcrease = 1000;
         SaveFileDialog xsfd = new SaveFileDialog()
         {
             FileName = "Book1",
             DefaultExt = ".xlsx",
             Filter = "Excel Document|*.xlsx",
             InitialDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)).ToString()
         };
         Nullable<bool> result = xsfd.ShowDialog();
         System.Data.DataTable batchFCSB = new System.Data.DataTable();
         int row = 0;
         if (result == true)
         {

             DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
             batchFCSB = DetailReportFCBuySell.ToDataTable();
             Collection.Add(row, batchFCSB);
             row = 1;
             PageIndex++;
             for (long k = NoOfRecords; k < DetailReportFCBuySell.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords; k=+ NoOfRecords)

             {
                 new AlxServiceClient().Using(channel =>
                 {
                     DetailReportFCBuySell = new ObservableCollection<DLReports.FCBuySellDetail>();
                     DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
                     batchFCSB = new System.Data.DataTable();
                     batchFCSB = DetailReportFCBuySell.ToDataTable();
                     Collection.Add(row, batchFCSB);
                     row++;
                     NoOfRecords = NoOfRecords + RecordsIcrease;

                 });
             }
}
```

Comment: which line is giving error?

Comment: i had attached an image with this ,  the l looping for (long k = NoOfRecords; k < DetailReportFCBuySell.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords; k=+ NoOfRecords)
{
}